How can I interpret this SAS code on dataframe?
I have below sas code
data original_data;
    input x y z z1;
    datalines;
1 4 76 1
2 3 49 0
2 3 85 0
4 5 88 0
2 2 90 1
;
run;

/*view dataset*/
proc print data=original_data;


data original_data_1 ;
set original_data;
length New_Col $30.;
New_Col = 'AAA';
if (z > 80) then New_Col = 'BBB';

proc print data=original_data_1;

data data_2;
set original_data_1;
if first.y then zzz = "Y";
else delete;
by New_Col y;
run;

proc print data=data_2;

I could not understand the part
if first.y then zzz = "Y";
else delete;
by New_Col y;

What is basically happening here?
Any interpretation would be helpful

That code cannot run.  BY statement does not use commas.  Also it is poor practice to put the BY statement so far away from the SET/MERGE/UPDATE/MODIFY statement that it applies to.  SAS might not care but you will confuse the poor humans that have to try to understand what you are trying to do.

What is a "dataframe"?  Are you trying to translate to some other language? What language?

@Tom I removed the comma. I am trying to understand what would be equivalent code in python?

BY group processing in a data step will create FIRST. and LAST. temporary flag variables to indicate if the current observation is the first (or last) observation in the group of observation with this value of named variable (within the current value of all preceeding variables from the BY statement).
So FIRST.Y is true for the first observation in each group of observations defined by the values of NEW_COL and Y.
So this data step
data data_2;
  set original_data_1;
  by New_Col y;
  if first.y then zzz = "Y";
  else delete;
run;

is selecting just the first observation for each group, since all others are deleted. It is also making the variable ZZZ have the value 'Y' on every observation.
Note when using the BY statement the data step will expect the data to already have been sorted unless you add the keyword NOTSORTED to the BY statement.  Your example dataset just happens to have the observations where Z is greater than 80 after all of the other observations.  But for other data since there is no sort step after the step that creates NEW_COL it is likely that this step will fail without adding a sort step before it.

Thanks for the explanation. However why do I get data_2  as 0 number of rows? I was expecting data_2  should have two rows because there the 2 groups based on the by statement

also, is this a correct line if first.y then zzz = str(first.x) + str(first.y);? I have basically try to concatenate x and y values from the first row. But if I understood your statement then both first.x and first.y are True, right? Then, how exactly I get access to the values?

Huh?  If you want the value of Y you reference the variable Y.  Just like in any other language.

zzz = str(x) + str(y)? Is it what you are saying? Apologies if my question is too naive. I am new to SAS, and found that it is pretty different from other similar language like R/Python

You seem to have veered off into a different question. No idea what str() does. Does it generate a number? Otherwise how could you add the results ?

You can't have first.X if X is not on your BY statement.
Try to concatenate x and y values from the first row. => if first.VAR then Z=catt(X,Y). Check which cat function you need.


Why do I get data_2 as 0 number of rows?

Check your log. The message
> ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set WORK.ORIGINAL_DATA_1

is self-explanatory. Always check your log. Always. Even if there's a result.

if first.y then zzz = str(first.x) + str(first.y)

Also, there's no str() function in SAS. Also first.x is a boolean.

Thanks for pointing this out. However why WORK.ORIGINAL_DATA_1 needs to be sorted in SAS, and what basis? In Python/R I dont need this, right?

If you use a BY statement, you need sorted (or indexed) data.

So I need a indexed data. Any suggestion how can I make WORK.ORIGINAL_DATA_1 indexed so that my code work?

You can use
data original_data_1 (index=...); set original_data; ....  Using proc sort is probably an easier option though.
